# Transitivity of a binary relation on the power set

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm studying for a test and there's a question that I've tried and I don't understand:

> Let $E$ be a binary relation on a set $A$; let a binary relation $F$ on $\mathcal P (A) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ be: $(B,C) \in F \iff \exists b \in B, \exists c \in C : (b,c)\in E$. If $E$ is transitive is $F$ transitive?

(I need to prove it if so).

Comment: Could you precise the quantificators in $(B,C) \in F \iff b\in B,c\in C : (b,c)\in E$ ? Is it "there exists $b \in B$ and $c \in C$", or "for all $b,c$" ?

Comment: @C.Dubussy  Exists

Comment: The relation E={{1,2},{3,4}} already disproves the first point, it seems, since {1} and {2,3} are related by F and {2,3} and {4} are related by F but {1} and {4} are not.

Comment: @Did wow!!! thank you so much! what about second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation E={{1,2},{3,4}} already disproves the first point, it seems, since {1} and {2,3} are related by F and {2,3} and {4} are related by F but {1} and {4} are not.